# Interesting weird TikZ behaviour

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-graphdrawing, drawing

I was trying to draw a grid of points with the weights of the points as the average of `x` and `y`:

```tex
\usepackage{tikz}

...

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \x in {1,2,3,4,5,6} {
        \foreach \y in {1,2,3,4,5,6} {
            \fill (\x, \y) circle ({(\x + \y)/2});
        }
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

...
```

[image: screen-shot-of-unexpected-blob]

The output is unexpected(Screenshot attached)!

Does anyone know what is happening? I am using Lualatex on overleaf.

edit 1:

Solved the original problem:

[image: solved-diagonally increasing weights]

but need an explanation of the earlier behaviour.

Comment: Why do you think it is wrong. As far as I can see the code does exactly what you ask it. (it is easier to see using `\draw` instead of `\fill`). Remember a number with no unit is assumed to be in the standard units in tikz, aka cm. So for (6,6) I'd expect it to draw a circle centered at (6,6) with a radius of 6cm)

Comment: As @daleif said, a value with units uses the canvas coordinate system, one without the *xyz* coordinate system. See [the manual](https://tikz.dev/tikz-coordinates#sec-13.1) for more about this. If you want to be consistent and use the *xyz* for both, scale the radius down by using, say, `/30` instead of `/2` (which gives a max radius of 0.4).

Comment: Please post complete examples people can compile and never, ever post pictures of code.

Comment: Hi, thanks, @daleif